# Stop AVPlayer music in another controller

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

so I have this variable in my delegate named AppDelegate.h:

```
AVAudioPlayer *introSound;
```

It plays continuously during first load.

```
[introSound stop];
```

---

What I want to do is stop it from a separate controller, firstController.m.

I tried

```
[AppDelegate.introSound stop];
```

but it threw an error saying:

> error: expected ':' before '.' token

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean a compiler error?  AppDelegate refers to the class, not to the instance of the class that is your application delegate.  To get that from anywhere, do this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.introSound stop];
```

You also need to make sure that introSound is a property, not just an instance variable of AppDelegate.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. Though I added it as: AppDelegate*appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

use this way catch videos/audios in simple and best.do this

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request1 setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSString *documentFolderPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSFileManager *fileManager1 = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *videosFolderPath = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"videos"]; 
//NSString* videosFolderPath = [@"~/Documents/bar.mp3" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSLog(@"video  path:%@",videosFolderPath);
//Check if the videos folder already exists, if not, create it!!!
BOOL isDir;
if (([fileManager1 fileExistsAtPath:videosFolderPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) == FALSE) {
    //[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:videosFolderPath attributes:nil];
    [fileManager1 createDirectoryAtPath:videosFolderPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
}
```

Comment: Again, your answer does not deal with the problem the OP is having. Please read the question *properly* before you answer.